# My query only returns 1 row. I expect more

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-server-2012, isnull

I am trying to sum values in a result set on a table with 2 joins.

I have a table called Limit.
A Limit has many Allocations.
A Limit also has many Extensions.
Both Allocations and Extensions have one Entity.

When I specify the Limit with an Oid in my where clause, I get one record returned. Even though the Limit has 9 Allocations. 
If the Limit has 9 Allocations and 0 Extensions, I get still get 1 returned.
Even thought the Limit has Zero Extensions, I still expect the 9 Allocations.
I hope this makes sense. Here is my Updated query:
-----I updated my query with this. I am now getting the correct amount of records for the given limit. I get 9 records:------

```
select 
convert(varchar(100), l.oid)  AS keyfield,
l.oid as Limit, 
la.SourceEntity as SourceEntity,
SUM(ISNULL(la.ARLimit, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(le.ARLimit, 0)) AS ARLimit, 
SUM(ISNULL(la.MTMLimit, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(le.MTMLimit, 0)) AS MTMLimit, 
SUM(ISNULL(la.Volume, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(le.Volume, 0)) AS Volume, 
SUM(ISNULL(la.MaxTenor, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(le.MaxTenor, 0)) AS MaxTenor
from limit l
left join limitallocation la
on l.oid = la.limit
left join limitextension le
on l.oid = le.limit
where l.Oid = '893de7ad-0ed2-462f-8bac-a26718b3e798'
GROUP BY l.Oid, la.SourceEntity
```

Comment: Please include which DB you are using as a tag.

Answer (score 1):

By using join you are expecting a result on the joined table, if there is no result then it will fail.

If you still wand the data you have regardless if there is a matching record on the table your joining, you need to use left join.

```
select 
convert(varchar(100), l.oid)  AS keyfield,
l.oid as Limit,
se.Oid as SourceEntity, 
SUM(ISNULL(la.ARLimit, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(le.ARLimit, 0)) AS ARLimit, 
SUM(ISNULL(la.MTMLimit, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(le.MTMLimit, 0)) AS MTMLimit, 
SUM(ISNULL(la.Volume, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(le.Volume, 0)) AS Volume, 
SUM(ISNULL(la.MaxTenor, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(le.MaxTenor, 0)) AS MaxTenor
from limit l
join limitallocation la
on l.oid = la.limit
left join limitextension le
on l.oid = le.limit
join 
dbo.SourceEntity as se 
on la.SourceEntity = se.oid 
and le.SourceEntity = se.Oid
where l.Oid = '893de7ad-0ed2-462f-8bac-a26718b3e798'
GROUP BY l.Oid, se.Oid
```

Comment: I tried this on each Allocations and Extensions. Still 0 results.

Comment: What happens when you dont join on Source Entitiy

Comment: Actually. I just put a Left Join on SourceEntity and I did receive 1 records. Just the Allocations. But I still expect all 9 Allocation records.

Comment: I updated my query. I added left joins to my query. I am now getting results even though there are zero extensions on a Limit. But it still just returns 1 record. The given Limit has 9 Allocations. I still expect all 9 Allocations returned.

Comment: Thank You! I removed the left join on Source Entity. I added a source entity field from Allocations instead. And I got 9 records back! Thanks for your help! I will update my query above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Left Join on the tables, as you have not specified type of the join inner join will be applied because of which only matching rows of all the tables in the Join will be displayed.

The table from which you want to get the records in the join no matter if the record exists in the the other table should be used as Left table.

In your case if you want to get all the data in **Limit** table with **Oid** = '893de7ad-0ed2-462f-8bac-a26718b3e798' you should use this table on the Left in Join after forming the result of this if you want to get all the data of **limitallocation** no matter whether the data exists in **limitextension**  table then **limitallocation** should be used on Left side.

Your query will be

```
select convert ( VARCHAR ( 100), L.OID) as KEYFIELD
        ,L.OID as limit
        ,SE.OID as SOURCEENTITY
        ,sum ( ISNULL ( LA.ARLIMIT, 0)) + sum ( ISNULL ( LE.ARLIMIT, 0)) as ARLIMIT
        ,sum ( ISNULL ( LA.MTMLIMIT, 0)) + sum ( ISNULL ( LE.MTMLIMIT, 0)) as MTMLIMIT
        ,sum ( ISNULL ( LA.VOLUME, 0)) + sum ( ISNULL ( LE.VOLUME, 0)) as VOLUME
        ,sum ( ISNULL ( LA.MAXTENOR, 0)) + sum ( ISNULL ( LE.MAXTENOR, 0)) as MAXTENOR
from limit L
         left join LIMITALLOCATION LA on L.OID = LA.limit
         left join LIMITEXTENSION LE on L.OID = LE.limit
         left join DBO.SOURCEENTITY as se
             on la.SourceEntity = se.oid
             and le.SourceEntity = se.Oid
where l.Oid = '893de7ad-0ed2-462f-8bac-a26718b3e798'
GROUP BY l.Oid, se.Oid
```